# Illumos(derivative of OpenSolaris) supports x86 32 bit currently

Tags: opensolaris

Does illumos support i686(x86 32 bit) currently? 
When I checked the forum, nothing came of this sort.

Answer (score 1):

Since [OpenIndiana](https://www.openindiana.org/download/) and [Peter Tribble](http://www.petertribble.co.uk/Solaris/illumos-SolarisSIG.pdf) talk about 32 bit support, I would say illumos must work on 32 bit.

According to the second link, SmartOS offers only 64 bits, but it's likely a deliberate choice.

illumos [requires](https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Project+Ideas#) only a Pentium (i686) processor.

Comment: I m thinking about source code support for 32 bit. I also have wish for porting to ARM.

Comment: What does "source code support" mean? illumos can also run 32 bit executables, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I meant we can compile the source code for 32-bit machines

Comment: See also https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Raspberry+Pi+Bring-Up

Comment: If OpenIndiana is provided for 32 bit, illumos must be compilable for 32 bit too... And illumos only requires a Pentium processor, by the way. https://wiki.illumos.org/display/illumos/Project+Ideas#

Comment: They say that they are removing pre Pentium code (cmpxchg8b aka F00F). This means they are removing 32-bit?

Comment: Pentium is 32 bit, don't you remember the processor of the mid-90's? If they keep Pentium, they provide 32 bit support.
Also, OpenIndiana offers 32 bit explicitly, isn't that enough by itself as proof?

Comment: OpenIndiana is off already:

"From 2017.04 onwards running on 32-bit systems is not supported anymore and the userland is being migrated progressively to 64-bit only."